# Have content sections in WPF vertical until it fills space then horizontal

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml

I'm trying to figure out a way to organize content a proper way horizontally.

I have a very wide but short space. And it is split up into different sections.
I want each section to have a vertical orientation but once it has used up all vertical space it should spill over to a new "column" to its right.

Here is a visual showing you what I mean. Each color is a different section.

[image: mspaint visual]

A horizontal stack panel containing each section is halfway there but I'm not sure what element to use for each individual section.

Comment: have u tried WrapPanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate `ListView` for each color with a `WrapPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`, and don't forget to disable the `HorizontalScrollBar` in each `ListView`

```
<Grid >    
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsLv1}" Background="Black" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle  Height="25" Width="100" Fill="White"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**The Result**

[image]